# Google translate modifies an external link - how to prevent that?

Tags: google-translate

I let my pages dynamically get translated by offering a link at the top of my site that reloads the page via `translate.google.com`, e.g.: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=en&tl=de&u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F

That works well in general.

But the problem is that Google also modifies *every* link inside a `<a href` tag, no matter that the URL points to. The idea of this is that any links to further web pages the visitor might follow will also get translated.

**However**, on my website have a URL that's not pointing to another website but it's a **[custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app)** (such as `<a href="myapp://something"`). And that's a problem:

Unfortunately, Google modifes even that link that's not a http URL, prefixing it with a `https` link, which destroys the functionality of that link's original scheme. And that's a major problem for me.

I'd consider it a bug that Google Translate modifies non-http links this way, but try telling that to Google `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

#### In short:

Is there a way to make Google Translate not to insert its own https redirection into a specific URL inside an `<a>` tag? Adding `translate="no"` to the hyperlink tag only stops the translation of the text shown for the link, but not the modification of the link itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around:

If I do not use `//` in the custom URL, then the URL won't get rewritten. Which means I must create the link like this:

```
<a href="myapp:something">
```

instead of:

```
<a href="myapp://something">
```

Sadly, that changes the expected behavior of the link, so that's not a solution in my particular case.

Comment: Perhaps this is part of the the solution; after translation you can do a quick find/replace to insert the two slashes where they belong.